# What operations result in automatic creation of SQL Server statistics?

Tags: sql-server

My understanding is that creating an index automatically creates statistics for that column.

What else results in auto creation of statistics? For example - Does SQL Server create statistics for every column that has ever appeared in a WHERE clause?

Comment: About histograms in statistics - this is from the [official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver15): *To create the histogram, the Query Optimizer **sorts the column values**, computes the number of values that match each distinct column value, and then aggregates the column values into a maximum of 200 contiguous histogram steps* - so statistics are **always** sorted - whether there's an index on the column or not ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver15)

> When the automatic create statistics option, AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS is ON, the Query Optimizer creates statistics **on individual columns in the query predicate,** as necessary, to improve cardinality estimates for the query plan.
>
> These single-column statistics are created on columns that do not already have a histogram in an existing statistics object.
>
> When the Query Optimizer creates statistics as a result of using the AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS option, the statistics name starts with **_WA**.
>
> You can use the following query to determine if the Query Optimizer has created statistics for a query predicate column.
>
> ```
> SELECT OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id) AS object_name,  
>     COL_NAME(sc.object_id, sc.column_id) AS column_name,  
>     s.name AS statistics_name  
> FROM sys.stats AS s 
> INNER JOIN sys.stats_columns AS sc  
>     ON s.stats_id = sc.stats_id AND s.object_id = sc.object_id  
> WHERE s.name like '_WA%'  
> ORDER BY s.name;
> ```

That includes `WHERE` predicate:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE col = ?;    -- here tab.col
```

and `JOIN` predicate(to determine physical join type: NESTED LOOPS/MERGE/HASH):

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 
  ON tab1.id = tab2.tab_1_id; -- here tab2.tab_1_id
```

Comment: In the 2nd example - what about 'tab1.id'? What's the reason for you to mention only the 'tab2.tab_1_id' please?

Comment: @variable It could be as well, but most of the time the ID is already defined as PK, which is not always the case for FK columns(often they do not have covering index)

Comment: So is it only WHERE and JOINS?

Comment: WHERE/JOINS/creation of index. I could recommend: https://eightkb.online/previous/ session: "Demystifying Statistics in SQL Server"

Comment: Wow thanks for pointing at this!